# How does one remove the Grub Star Labs Theme in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: grub2

How do I remove the Star Labs Theme in Ubuntu 18.04

I have run the command `sudo apt remove starlabstheme`

I have Grub Customizer and created a new theme for Grub but the the Star Labs theme still loads.

Please can someone point me in the right direction? Searched the internet and looked in the Grub file but cannot see where it is pointing to the Star Labs theme.

Answer (score 0):

You should first completely remove StarLabs packages using

```
sudo apt autoremove starlabs
```

Comment: It seems OP already tried a similar command.